# Is There a Python alternate statement

Tags: python

I was wondering if in Python if you could have like an alternate statement like: if input = bad: print('That's Not Good'),Heres my code:

```
print('Hello')
print('What Is Your Name?')
myname = input ()
print('It Is Good To Meet You, ' + myname)
print('How Are You Today')  
emotion = input ()
print('Me Too!')
```

Please help if you can.

Comment: Do you know if/else if/else statements?

Answer (score 2):

Look into iF Statements for Python. Check out the documentation for Python online,but essentially its just:

```
if [condition]:
    [statements]
elif [condition]:
    [statements]
else:
    [statements]
```

Comment: No need for parens around conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use an if/ else if/ statement.

```
if myname == "guido":
    print("hello guido")
elif myname == "dmr":
    print("You aren't dennis")
else:
    print("that is a bad input.")
```

Comment: No need for parens, and you should make your indentation consistent.

Comment: @NedBatchelder sorry about the indents I had a mishap while formatting my answer.  As for the parens it's just a habit of mine, thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: emotion = input('How are you today? ')
How are you today? bad

In [4]: if emotion == 'bad':
   ...:     print("That`s not good")
   ...: else:
   ...:     print("Great!")
   ...:     
That`s not good
```

Effectively, what you need is:

```
print('Hello')
print('What Is Your Name?')
myname = input()
print('It Is Good To Meet You, ' + myname)
print('How Are You Today')  
emotion = input()
if emotion == 'bad':
    print("That`s not good")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. In fact, it is almost exactly the way you say it. It is called the if statement:

```
emotion = input()

if emotion == bad:
    print ("That's not good!")
else:
    print ('Me too!')
```